# LinkedList Index Counter

Tags: java, linked-list

I am building a indexOf method.

It returns and index of an object.

```
public int indexOf(Token obj) {
    int store = 0;
    int tempIndex = 0;
    Node nodeRef = head;
    while(nodeRef.next != null ){
        tempIndex++;
        if(obj.equals(nodeRef.getObject())){
            store = tempIndex;  
        }
        nodeRef = nodeRef.next; 
    }
    System.out.println("Index");
    return store;
    }
```

My problem is it's not looking at the last object because the last objects .next refrence is null(naturally). I can see the issue but the solution aludes me. I have tried adding on something like;

```
if(nodeRef.next == null && obj.equals(nodeRef.getObject())){
     tempIndex++;
     store = nodeRef.next
}
```

Does not seem to help though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your loop condition to

`while(nodeRef != null ){`

This should basically fix it.

Comment: And ... what happened?

Comment: @peter.petrov - I am not sure about this.. but he is doing obj.equals(nodeRef.getObject()). Now, unless he has overriden equals() in his class, if he passes a new object, they will be comapred by reference and this goes against the OP's logic right
?

Comment: @WhoAmI Well, this might be an issue too. I was trying to help him fix his code so that it looks at the last node. What it does when looking at it is another question.

Comment: I have overridden toString()

Comment: Yer this is really just a small peace of the overall code.

Comment: @user2998504 - you also have to override equals(), else obj.equals(nodeRef.getObject()) might fail.

Comment: Override equals in Token, this is what WhoAmI means.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have however overidden equals in token :)

Comment: Woops sorry for the wild goose chase.The issue was with another method down the line, I don think awswell as this one. remove the .next fixed it. Many thannks

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested into a simpler solution, have a look at this sample code. Perhaps you will find something useful:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node head = new Node();
    head.addNext().addNext().addNext();
    Node node = head;
    while (node != null) {
        System.out.printf("Index of node no. [%d] is [%d]\n", node.no, indexOf(head, node));
        node = node.next;
    }
}

public static int indexOf(Node head, Node node) {
    Node cursor = head;
    for (int index = 0; cursor != null; index++) {
        if (cursor.equals(node)) return index;
        cursor = cursor.next;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Node with no [%d] not member of chain", node.no));
}

class Node {

    Node next = null;
    final int no;

    Node() {
        this.no = 0;
    }

    private Node(Node parent) {
        this.no = parent.no + 1;
    }

    Node addNext() {
        this.next = new Node(this);
        return this.next;
    }
}
```